# Load image from listview to next Activity

Tags: android, android-listview

I am using `Listview` to display image and data using json parser,

**But when i click on one of the list item image is not displaying in next activity i.e in detailed Activity.**

I am using the following code to display image. Can any one guide me in right path? Any help wud be appreciated.

```
// Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String title = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title)).getText().toString();
            String date = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date)).getText().toString();
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
            String content = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content)).getText().toString();
             // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL);
             try {
                 posts = json.getJSONArray(KEY_POSTS);

    // looping through all song nodes <song>
            for(int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = posts.getJSONObject(i);
                // Storing each json item in variable

                String url = null;
                String slug = null;
                try {
                JSONArray atta = c.getJSONArray("attachments");
                for(int j = 0; j < atta.length(); j++){
                    JSONObject d = atta.getJSONObject(j);

                    slug = d.getString(KEY_SLUG);

                    JSONObject images = d.getJSONObject(KEY_IMAGES);

                    JSONObject thumbnail = images.getJSONObject(KEY_THUMB_URL);
                    url = thumbnail.getString(KEY_URL);

                }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }



            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SampleDesp.class);
            in.putExtra(KEY_TITLE, title);
            in.putExtra(KEY_DATE, date);
            in.putExtra(KEY_NAME, name);
            in.putExtra(KEY_CONTENT, content);
            in.putExtra(KEY_URL, url);      
            startActivity(in);

        }


             }catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                    }
        }

    });   

}
```

}

And in **Singlemenuitem.java**

```
 // getting intent data
        Intent in = getIntent();
        final String url1 = in.getStringExtra(KEY_URL);

        ImageView imgv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgdesc);
        ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(url1, imgv);





        // Get JSON values from previous intent
        final String title = in.getStringExtra(TAG_TITLE);
        String date = in.getStringExtra(TAG_DATE);
        String name = in.getStringExtra(TAG_NAME);
        final String content = in.getStringExtra(TAG_CONTENT);

        // Displaying all values on the screen
        TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_label);
        TextView lblCost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email_label);
        TextView lblDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_label);
        TextView lblCont = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.content_label);

        lblName.setText(title);
        lblCost.setText(date);
        lblDesc.setText(name);
        lblCont.setText(content);
```

Comment: you're passing the null URL `String url = null;   in.putExtra(KEY_URL, url); ` in your `ItemOnClick`, then trying to read it in your `SingleMenuItem.java`?

Comment: now changed String url to String url= KEY_URL, and when i run getting exception plz look into logcat posted

Comment: from these lines: `01-23 16:27:03.634: I/System.out(699): Image bitmap object from url***$$$$$$$$null 01-23 16:27:03.634: I/System.out(699): In the else where there is null bitmap>>>>>>>>> 01-23 16:27:03.654: W/System.err(699): java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: url 01-23 16:27:03.654` Please check if your URL is a valid URL

Comment: I have edited the code and it works can i do in this way is it the right method to do? the loop repeats twice in MainActivity.java

Comment: no its not working getting all images as and when i refresh

Comment: What is the problem you are currently having? You said images are being displayed? But?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you All for your help and support, Just Add the below code in MainActivity class

```
    // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = songsList.get(position);

            Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SampleDesp.class);
            in.putExtra(KEY_TITLE, map.get(KEY_TITLE));
            in.putExtra(KEY_DATE, map.get(KEY_DATE));                         
            in.putExtra(KEY_NAME, map.get(KEY_NAME));
            in.putExtra(KEY_CONTENT, map.get(KEY_CONTENT));
            in.putExtra(KEY_URL, map.get(KEY_URL));

            startActivity(in);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you want to get the url from, but this can't be helping:-

String url = null;

Comment: images are obtained from parsing json response obtained from webservice

Comment: That may be, but you take fields from the the selected list item and place them in the intent to start the detail activity, none of them appear to be the url you need, and then to top it off, you explicitly set the url to null or "KEY_URL" in the intent. KEY_URL is probably the key to retrieve the url from the extra fields.

Answer (score 0):

First of try to intialize the url here

```
 String url = null;// here
  in.putExtra(KEY_URL, url);
```

Because of this null value you are not getting any thing in your next activity

Comment: this url is parsed from json response i cant initialize it to specific image url

Answer (score 0):

I may not sure, change into BitMap and pass tat BitMap value into another activity

Answer (score 0):

**Here you can use this follwing code for load image from listview to next Activity:**

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailActivity.class);8
                    String pic =array.get(position).getImage();
                    intent.putExtra("Photo", pic);

                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            });
```

**Here DetailActivity.java class :**

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageLoader imageLoader=AppController.getmInstance().getmImageLoader();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        NetworkImageView imageView= (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view_detail);
        imageView.setImageUrl(getIntent().getExtras().getString("Photo"),imageLoader);
    }
}
```

Thank you