# How to send an image downloaded by volley to the next activity

Tags: android, image, android-volley

I am using `volley` to download **images and text** on a `listview` in my activity.
On clicking a row i pass both the image and the text to **Details activity**.
On **details activity** i would like to pass only the `Image` to yet another activity.

**After research on S/O i found a code that works:**

```js
BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) ((NetworkImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img2))
                    .getDrawable();
            Bitmap bitmapzoom=bd.getBitmap();
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bd.getBitmap().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
            byte[] imgByte = baos.toByteArray();
            Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ZoomImage.class);
            intent.putExtra("image", imgByte);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

**And on the next activity i retrieve it like:**

```js
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        byte[] b = extras.getByteArray("image");

        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
        BitmapDrawable background = new BitmapDrawable(bmp);
        findViewById(R.id.img2).setBackgroundDrawable(background);
```

However the image is being placed as a **background image**.I would like to place the image in my `ImageView.`
**Not as a background like the way it is done on the code above.**

Currently setting the image on the ImageView  has not been successfull.Any suggestions will be welcomed.

layout.xml

```js
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.softtech.stevekamau.buyathome.ZoomImage">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/back"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/root_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img2"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:scaleType="matrix"
            android:maxHeight="100dp"
            android:maxWidth="50dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

How it looks as a background:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: To set the imageview actual image using a bitmap, not the bitmapdrawable:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
byte[] b = extras.getByteArray("image");

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
findViewById(R.id.img2).setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Careful in passing large images between activities, it might not show the image in the other activity. Better to save to internal or external memory and then get it on the other activity.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply..but I had already tried this and i got error  `cannot resolve 'setImageResource(android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable)'`

Comment: Also getting same error `cannot resolve 'setImageBitmap(android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable)'`

Comment: set bmp instead of background. It needs a bitmap, not a bitmapDrawable. See the updated answer.

Comment: @SteveKamau Have you tried `ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img2);` and using API `setImageBitmap` as `imgView.setImageBitmap` it should set image to your `ImageView` instead of to its background

Answer (score 2):

get The Url of the image and pass it via bundle , later in activity you can use Picasso library to load it into view below is the code you may have a look.

```
private void setImageWithPicaso(String imageUrl) {
    if (!(imageUrl == null)) {
        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(imageUrl).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_background).into(imageView, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
                spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                AppLog.showToastMessage(getActivity(), "Image  loading failed!");

            }
        });
    } else {
        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        AppLog.showToastMessage(getActivity(), "Image  loading failed!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Substitute:

```
findViewById(R.id.img2).setBackgroundDrawable(background);
```

for:

```
findViewById(R.id.img2).setImageDrawable(background);
```

> However the image is being placed as a background image.I would like to place the image in my ImageView. Not as a background like the way it is done on the code above.

I think I get where your confusion is coming from. Am not sure you quite understand what an ImageView is.Your image is infact IN your imageview, else you wouldn't be seeing it.

Comment: Getting this error too `cannot resolve 'setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable)'`

Comment: Are you applying any styling to your image in the activity? Like rounded corners?

Comment: @ojonugwaochalifu, I think it would works. +1 for you

Comment: @HirenPatel, Yes it should, am using something very similar although mine is `RoundedBitmapDrawable`

Comment: Steve good you added your layout code, but am surprised it isn't working for you since am using something very similar with the only difference being mine is `RoundedBitmapDrawable` and not `BitmapDrawable`

Comment: How comes i am getting the error?SetImageDrawable cannot be resolved.

Comment: Anyway +1 for your effort

Comment: Doesn't feel right since I haven't actually helped you solve your problem.Can you show how the image is been displayed? a screengrab or something.

Comment: Please see my edit.The reason why i would want to pass the image into an ImageView is because i would like to add zoom effect to the image

Comment: this doesn't work because background is a BitmapDrawable, not an actual Drawable

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend that you pass the image data between activities.

The recommended way is to save it in disk, and pass the filepaths between activities.